# Suppose that $\int_{E_1} f < \infty$. Show that $\int_{\bigcap_{j=1}^\infty E_j} f = \lim_{j\to \infty} \int_{E_j} f.$

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $f : \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R$ be a simple function and $E_1 \supset E_2 \supset \dots$ decreasing sequence of measurable subsets of $\Bbb R^n$. Suppose that $\int_{E_1} f < \infty$. Show that $$\int_{\bigcap_{j=1}^\infty E_j} f = \lim_{j\to \infty} \int_{E_j} f.$$

Since $f$ is simple we have that $$\int_{\bigcap_{j=1}^\infty E_j} f = \sum_{k=1}^n a_k \cdot\mu \left(\bigcap_{j=1}^\infty E_j\right)$$ but by the properties of $\mu$ and the fact that $E_i$'s are decreasing the measure $\mu \left(\bigcap_{j=1}^\infty E_j\right) = \lim_{j \to \infty} \mu(E_j).$ So in essence we have $$\int_{\bigcap_{j=1}^\infty E_j} f = \sum_{k=1}^n a_k \cdot\mu \left(\bigcap_{j=1}^\infty E_j\right)= \sum_{k=1}^n a_k \cdot \lim_{j\to \infty} \mu(E_j) = \lim_{j \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n a_k \cdot \mu(E_j) = \lim_{j \to \infty} \int_{E_j} f.$$

Am I approaching this correctly? I don't seem to be needing the fact that $\int_{E_1} f < \infty$ which seems a bit odd.

Comment: Do you already know a limit theorem?  Dominated convergence theorem, say?

Comment: You did not say $f$ is nonnegative, so when you say $\int_{E_1}f < \infty$ do you allow $\int_{E_1} f = -\infty$?  Maybe you should assume $\int_{E_1}|f| < \infty$.

Comment: What you say is all mixed up.  The sets that make $f$ simple need not be the sets $E_j$.

Comment: I do know the dominated convergence theorem. Also yes $f$ is non-negative.